# INVALID_TAB_OPERATION on textTabs update for a docusign recipient

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to update the textTabs for a particular envelope recipient of a draft Docusign envelope.

For this I am using the PUT EnvelopeRecipientTabs endpoint. But I am always getting this error.

I intend to update the value of an existing text tab of the particular recipient.

```
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "requireAll": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "recipientId": "3",
            "tabId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "errorDetails": {
                "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
                "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  Tab not found in envelope."
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying a `tabId`? You need to. Before your [EnvelopeRecipientTabs::update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update) call, call [EnvelopeRecipientTabs::list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/list) to learn the tabId.

Comment: The list tabs endpoint gives empty result for my envelope. Initially I was not passing any tabIds in the envelope, but then I tried with new envelope with text tabIds but still got the same error on updating recipient text tabs. Also in this case, the list tabs gave empty payload.  @Larry

Comment: Can you please share your code for envelope creation by editing your qs, it seems tabs are not getting added in envelope creation call, thats the reason for empty response in list tabs API call.